# HTTP Request Extended Info

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, httprequest

I've got this annoying scenario in which a request is sent successfully (I'm getting 200 from the destination, which is a "blackbox" destination).

On the other hand I've got a scenario which the request is not sent successfully to the same destination (I'm getting 500) from the destination.

Obviously, the requests are different, and I want to compare it.

So,

I've printed the headers:

```
Dim headers As String = String.Empty
Dim keys As String() = httpRequest.Headers.AllKeys

For i As Integer = 0 To keys.Length
    ' Exit condition if the value is three.
    Dim headerKey = keys(0)
    headers &= headerKey & "=" & httpRequest.Headers(headerKey) & Environment.NewLine
    i += 1
Next
```

And I've printed other stuff along the way (Address, Client Certificates, etc.)

But if anyone (who already troubleshooted such scenario or just have it) can provide some vb.net method that prints everything a request contains, from header to body, it would be mostly appreciated.

Tried Googling for such method, but didn't find it,
c# sample will do just fine as well.

Comment: You could use a local proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see what's going out and coming in.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`enable tracing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx) by adding the following section to your `App.config/Web.config`:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.Net" tracemode="protocolonly" maxdatasize="1024">
            <listeners>
                <add name="System.Net" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="System.Net"
             type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="network.log" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Now run your program and inspect the contents of the `network.log` file that will be generated in the same directory as your executable. It will contain verbose information about the HTTP request.

Alternatively I may suggest you using [`Fiddler`](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) which is a great tool for inspecting HTTP traffic from the local machine.

Comment: Isn't Fiddler for use with browser only? I've used [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865), [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) in the past for scenarios like these.

Comment: No, absolutely not, Fiddler has nothing to do with a browser. Just install it and enjoy the full HTTP traffic going out from your machine.

Comment: I tried it, but I don't get the log file. Checked in every folder of the project, any ideas?